# Go: Inline string concatenation

Tags: go

I need to `call os.Open` to open a file. I have the path `./XML/` and the filename `foo.xml`, which changes each time. That is I have an array of xml files read from a dir which I am trying to open one at a time (or threaded, doesn't matter).

I need to simple add `./XML/` to `SOMETHING.xml`. In Java this is trivial,

```
String a = "whatever", b = "whatever";
doSomething(a + b);
```

How is this done in Go? Google has failed me.

```
file, err := os.Open(????????????)
```

Comment: RTFM: https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_concatenation

Comment: kind of funny since you concatenate strings with a `+` operator in Go, just like Java, just like you have in your example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most portable way to do path concatenation is by using [`filepath.Join`](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Join):

```
import "path/filepath"

file, err := os.Open(filepath.Join("XML", fileinfo.Name()))
```